# Changing the actionbar menu state depending on fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to show/hide items in my action bar depending on which fragment is visible.

In my MainActivity I have the following

```
/* Called whenever invalidateOptionsMenu() is called */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(this.myFragment.isVisible()){
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_read).setVisible(true);
    }else{
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_read).setVisible(false);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This works great however, when the device is rotated there is a issue. After the rotation is complete onPrepareOptionsMenu is called again however this time **this.myFragment.isVisible() returns false**...and hence the menu item is hidden when clearly the fragment is visible (as far as whats shown on the screen).

Comment: Not sure but are you using the same fragment for both portrait and landscape mode or you add some other fragments as well in landscape mode? On rotation when it re-initializes itself are you sure it is getting attached to the FragmentActivity. You can check this by using fragment.isAdded() ?

Comment: Yes, in the activity onCreate method I do: this.myFragment = new MyListFragment(); and then this.myFragment is referenced through out the activity

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Edit: This is a quick and dirty fix, see [es0329's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223734/2669756) below for a better solution.

Try adding this attribute to your `activity` tag in your android manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: I wonder if android developers will ever be able to let go of this convention. The other solution posted here is much better.

Answer (score 25):

**Based on the [Fragments API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar), we can add items to the action bar on a per-Fragment basis with the following steps:
Create a `res/menu/fooFragmentMenu.xml` that contains menu items as you normally would for the standard menu.**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/newAction"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/newActionTitle"
        android:icon="@drawable/newActionIcon"/>
</menu>
```

**Toward the top of FooFragment's onCreate method, indicate that it has its own menu items to add.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ...
}
```

**Override onCreateOptionsMenu, where you'll inflate the fragment's menu and attach it to your standard menu.**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fooFragmentMenu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**Override onOptionItemSelected in your fragment, which only gets called when this same method of the host Activity/FragmentActivity sees that it doesn't have a case for the selection.**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.newAction:
            ...
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Then how can we provide back/up  button navigation?

Comment: May be you're a Google Android team Member. Very god !

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fragment's `setRetainInstance(true);` when your fragment is attached to the Activity. That way your fragment will retain it's current values and call the lifecycle when device rotated.